# how to remove the focus on disclosure panel's header

Tags: gwt

i noticed that whenever i click the disclosure panel's header, it got focused, namely you can see the black dotted border around the header, is there any way i can get rid of that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting css style `outline:0` on the Disclosure header:

```
.gwt-DisclosurePanel .header {
  outline:0;
}
```

See also http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/
Basically you need to remove the outline from the `a` anchor element.