# In GWT, how do I control how a widget is decorated to show it's got the focus?

Tags: gwt, focus

In general terms, how do I control in GWT the decoration that gets put on a widget, e.g. a TextBox, to show that it's the widget that's focussed? Google Chrome for example illuminates focussed widgets with a sort of orange border with round corners, but it's not the same border that you can control with the border instruction in CSS. (border: 3px black inset or whatever).

Specifically, I've got an HTML widget wrapped in a FocusPanel. I want the FocusPanel to respond to keypresses, which it does, but I want it to do it invisibly, without the orange border I mentioned in Google Chrome when I do FocusPanel.setFocus(true);.

Thanks!
Neil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the red border by setting the css `outline` to `0`. See: [how to remove the focus on disclosure panel's header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034312/how-to-remove-the-focus-on-disclosure-panels-header)?

Comment: Thanks Hilbrand, but it's not helping. I'm not using a DisclosurePanel, but a FocusPanel, and substituting FocusPanel for DisclosurePanel in the article you've linked to doesn't achieve anything. I've also tried setting the outline to 0 for HTML widgets, but the orange outline remains. How can I adapt what you've said to apply to an HTML wrapped in a FocusPanel? Thanks.

Comment: You need to set the outline at the exact html tag that has the focus. Using the browser inspector can reveal which element gets the focus border.

Comment: Ok. Well, my GWT's HTML widget has the focus border, but changing its css outline doesn't help. If I turn the outline off it still appears. If I do something completely spurious like outline: 3px solid #6374AB;, that appears as well as the orange outline I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: The outline is on html elements that have a `tabindex` attribute. In this case that's the FocusPanel. If you set the outline:0 on the FocusPanel it should hide the orange border.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Slightly cross because that's the first thing I tried when you first answered but I obviously did something wrong. Anyway, working now. Thanks very much.